# Como recuperar o ID do elemento selecionado no asp:Repeater via javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Eu tenho um `asp:Repeater` e preciso recuperar no **javascript** o **ID** do item referente ao registro exibido no `asp:Repeater`.

Veja como esta o meu `asp:Repeater`

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt_OnItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="div" runat="server" style="margin: 5px 0 5px 0; min-height: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px; width: 100%">
            <div style="width: 40%; float: left; position: relative">
                <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnID" Value='<%# Eval(" ID ") %>' />
                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNome" Text='<%# Eval(" Nome ") %>' />
            </div>
            <div style="width: 30%; float: left; position: relative">
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtData" ReadOnly="True" CssClass="Data" />
            </div>
            <div style="width: 30%; float: left; position: relative">
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnInformacoes" Text="Informações" Visible="False" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="linha1">
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Veja que eu tenho um `asp:HiddenField` que armazena o **ID**.

O que preciso é recuperar este **ID** para passar para a função **javascript** abaixo.

```
$.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "listas.aspx/Listar",
                data: "{'id':'" + "58" + "'}", // nesta linha, no lugar do 58, quero passar o ID que esta no meu asp:Repeater.
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Sucesso');
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('Erro');
                }
            });
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isto?

Comment: Você usa `MasterPage`?

Comment: @Jota eu uso sim.

Answer (score 2):

Consegui resolver o problema da seguinte maneira.

segue o código **javascript** com a solução:

```
$(".elemento").click(function () {
    var index = this.id.substr(this.id.length - 1, 1);
    var id = $("[id*='hdnID']")[index].value;
    $.ajax
       ({
           type: "POST",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           url: "listas.aspx/Listar",
           data: "{'id':'" + id + "'}",
           dataType: "json",
           success: function (data) {
                alert('Sucesso');
           },
           error: function (result) {
                alert('Erro');
           }
       });
});
```

Comment: Ribeiro de Agusto Então você pode marcar a resposta como certa.

Comment: Só posso aceitar minha própria resposta depois de 2 dias. Isso é bom, vai que alguém tem uma idéia melhor.